# Fix needed to Excel VBA flowchart using shapes

Tags: excel, vba

I found an old solution made by a user named n1ghthawk (2012!), using shapes to form a flowchart that can be filtered by selected shape(s).

Exactly what I need except that the code fails in a certain scenario with connectors. I have failed to fix this myself, so I would appreciate if someone could help me.

I will send a link to the file to respondents instead of posting code, as I think that will make it much easier to help. In the file, I have setup the shapes to show the failing scenario in the simplest possible form.

Comment: Please don't link (or just promise to link) to code. Instead, post enough information to answer the question, preferably as a [mcve]. Show the code that you are referring to, as well as your attempted modifications, and describe how it fails to do what you want it to do.

Comment: My apologies. It was just quite comprehensive, with two class modules and five procedures

Comment: Perhaps you could boil it down to a core issue -- such as how do I do *this* with connectors?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks John, for helping out.

A collegue of mine just pointed me in the right direction and these 3 lines stopped an infinite loop and made the script move on the the next shape, fixing the failing scenario:

```
For j = 1 To UBound(MyNames())
If thisshape.Name = MyNames(j) Then Exit Sub
Next
```

So the entire recursive Sub looks like this now:

```
Sub Get_LegUp(thisshape As Shape)

Dim con As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim dependentshape As Shape

'***
For j = 1 To UBound(MyNames())
    If thisshape.Name = MyNames(j) Then Exit Sub
Next
'***

namecount = namecount + 1
MyNames(namecount) = thisshape.Name

For i = 1 To shpconlist.Item(thisshape.Name).up.Count
    con = shpconlist.Item(thisshape.Name).up(i)

    namecount = namecount + 1
    MyNames(namecount) = con
    Set dependentshape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(con).ConnectorFormat.BeginConnectedShape

    Get_LegUp dependentshape

Next i
End Sub
```

If someone wants the code to recreate the functionality, just post back here and I will put it all in here.

Again, apologies for not following guidelines.

Comment: It is always fun when you fix a bug